# Software to manage monitoring notification e-mails?

Tags: linux, monitoring, mailing-list

We have several monitoring services that send notification e-mails when their alerts are triggered. In case of major incidents, many e-mails can be sent in short amount of time.

Notification e-mails from each monitoring service are sent to per-project mailing lists, to allow for easier configuration — when you have to subscribe a new employee to the list, you can do it in one place.

We're (ab)using google groups for notification mailing lists, but we want to move to a self-hosted solution.

Please advise, what mailing list management software would suit our needs?

Requirements:

- The solution must be redundant — we should be able to set it up on at least two physical machines, with shared configuration.
- Web archive is not necessary, but all e-mails must be stored on server, just in case.
- Open source is preferred.

Note that I say "mailing list" above, but, maybe, something simpler would do? (Like a properly configured forwarding e-mail address...)

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic on all [SE] sites. Please see the [FAQ].

Answer (score 1):

My favourite mailing list solution is still [GNU mailman](http://list.org/). It's open source and has web-accesible archives.

To make it redundant, you can set it up with `/var/lib/mailman` on shared storage and an active/backup setup of mailservers (you don't want active/active there).

Comment: Along with mailman, I'd recommend you use software such as: [nans](https://github.com/bobpattersonjr/nans) to reduce the verbosity of Nagios/Icinga without loosing any mail.